# Cannot GET /socket.io/1/

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have the following app with express/socket.io (the app is listening and live without any errors). When I http-request it I get the following error:

GET http://localhost:3030/socket.io/1/?t=1630097351846 404 (Not Found)

And on the socket.io reponse http://localhost:3030/socket.io at  I get:
`Cannot GET /socket.io`

Please help !!

```js
const socket=io.connect('http://localhost:3030/');
//const { Socket } = require("socket.io");
const videoGrid=document.getElementById('video-grid');
const myVideo=document.createElement('video');
myVideo.muted=true;

let myVideoStream
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video:true,
    audio:true
}).then(stream=>{
    myVideoStream=stream;
    addVideoStream(myVideo,stream);
})

// socket.emit('join-room');

const addVideoStream=(video,stream)=>{
    video.srcObject=stream;
    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata',()=>{
        video.play();
    })
    videoGrid.append(video);
}
```

```css
const express=require('express');
const app=express();
const server=require('http').Server(app);
const {v4: uuidv4}= require('uuid');
const io=require('socket.io-client')(server);
//import { io } from "socket.io-client";

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.redirect(`/${uuidv4()}`);
})

app.get('/:room',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('room',{roomId :req.params.room});
})

io.on('connection',socket=>{
    socket.on('join-room',()=>{
        console.log("Room Joined");
    })
})

//now need to import socket.io in script.js

// server.listen(app.get('3030'));
    app.listen(3030);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Zoom RJ</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/0.9.16/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="/node_modules/socket.io/client-dist/socket.io.js"></script> -->
    
    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="video-grid">

    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `const io=require('socket.io-client')` you are trying to use the client module as your server, should be using `socket.io-server`

Comment: tried, showing- Cannot find module "socket.io-server"
help!

Comment: You've installed the wrong socket.io module. Run `npm install socket.io --save` in your terminal then replace `require('socket-io-client')` with `require('socket.io');`.

Comment: Tried this too just, showing this in console-"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" with "socket.io/1/?t=1630098816512:1"
please help with it, I am stuck!